# How to open .net core implemented method in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

Recently, I saw one of developer on youtube was developing asp.net core application using Jetbrains Rider and when he want to see the implementation of `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` method (asp.net core method), he just open implementation (I am assuming by Ctrl+F12).

As of now I am using github to find method implementation Or https://source.dot.net/. Is there any way to link asp.net core source code directly in visual studio so we can simply open implementation of any method (by Ctrl+F12) when needed? When I tried Ctrl+F12 on `WebApplication.CreateBuilder` I got below message

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition

Answer (score 1):

Try [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), a free tool by JetBrains (the makers of Rider and ReSharper). It doesn't integrate with Visual Studio though but is great if you just want to decompile third party libraries.

JetBrains do have [discounts](https://www.jetbrains.com/store/#discounts) on their tools.

Answer (score 0):

Rider downloads the .pdb files from microsoft and is able to fetch source code inside the IDE.
If you want to use the same feature in Visual Studio, you can do this with the `Jetbrains Resharper Visual Studio Extension`.

Comment: It is paid and my job profile allow me to use VS Community edition only